# java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity cannot be cast to MainActivity

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am trying to do a login session using Volley, PHP, MySQL but my login layout won't load. I do not know what is happening and in my logcat it says " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.merylle.themoneyger/com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.MainActivity"

which is cause by "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.MainActivity"

Can someone help me identify my error? Here's my code

SessionManager.java

```
public class SessionManager {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE=0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MONEYGER";
    private static final String LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
    public static final String FIRSTNAME = "NAME";
    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String USERID = "USERID";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void createSession(String firstname, String email) {
        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(FIRSTNAME, firstname);
        editor.putString(EMAIL, email);

/*editor.putString(USERID, userid);*/

        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isLoggin(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void checkLogin() {
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((MainActivity)context).finish();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetail() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put(FIRSTNAME, sharedPreferences.getString(FIRSTNAME, null));
        user.put(EMAIL, sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL, null));

/*user.put(USERID, sharedPreferences.getString(USERID, null));*/

        return user;
    }

    public void logout() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((MainActivity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    TextView title;
    Typeface marcellus;
    private EditText emailuser, passworduser;
    TextView forgot;
    private Button login, register;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static String HttpURL = "http://10.0.2.2:63343/TheMoneyger/api/user-login.php?";
    SessionManager sessionManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        marcellus = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "marcellus.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(marcellus);

        emailuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        passworduser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtForgotPW);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String mEmail = emailuser.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = passworduser.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                    Login(mEmail, mPass);
                }
                else {
                    emailuser.setError("Please insert email");
                    passworduser.setError("Please insert password");
                }
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registration = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(registration);
            }
        });

        forgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent forgot = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPassword.class);
                startActivity(forgot);
            }
        });
    }

    private void Login(final String emailuser, final String passworduser) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String firstname = object.getString("firstname").trim();
                                    String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                                    String id = object.getString("userid").trim();

                                    sessionManager.createSession(firstname, email);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
                                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong.. " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong.. " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", emailuser);
                params.put("password", passworduser);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Home2.java

```
public class Home2 extends Fragment {
    private TextView profileName, profileEmail;
    CardView cv1, cv2, cv3, cv4, cv5, cv6;
    SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        sessionManager.checkLogin();

        cv1 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv1); //settings
        cv2 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv2); //profile
        cv3 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv3); //expenses summary
        cv4 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv4); //budget summary
        cv5 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv5); //report
        cv6 = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cv6); //logout

        profileName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileName); //display profilename
        profileEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileEmail); //display profileemail

        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        String mName = user.get(sessionManager.FIRSTNAME);
        String mEmail = user.get(sessionManager.EMAIL);

        profileName.setText(mName);
        profileEmail.setText(mEmail);
return view;
}
}
```

user-login.php

```
<?php    
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        require_once 'config.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username'";

        $response = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        $result = array();
        $result['login'] = array();

        if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

            if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {
                $index['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
                $index['email'] = $row['email'];

                array_push($result['login'], $index);

                $result['success'] = "1";
                $result['message'] = "success";
                echo json_encode($result);

                mysqli_close($db);
            } else {
                $result['success'] = "0";
                $result['message'] = "error";
                echo json_encode($result);

                mysqli_close($db);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized `sessionManager` with `LoginActivity`'s context:

```
sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
```

and then inside `SessionManager` class you use this:

```
((MainActivity)context).finish();
```

which throws the error.  
You can't cast `LoginActivity`'s context to `MainActivity`.  
Change to this:

```
((LoginActivity)context).finish();
```

After all it is `LoginActivity` you want to finish isn't it?

Comment: i did what you said and changed it to this public void checkLogin() {
        if (!this.isLoggin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((LoginActivity)context).finish();
        }
    } but there is still an error " android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity.LoginActivity"

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do. I just said that `context` in `SessionManager` is `LoginActivity`'s context and you can't use it to cast it to `MainActivity`.

Comment: It is already working. but now when i try to login i get this error in my JSON parsing. I have put a log before i call the JSONObject and this is in my logcat "Undefined index: password" @forpas

Comment: I can't say about this issue. Post another question with all the relevant code (not the above code if it does not have anything to do with new issue) and explain where the problem is. Also include the error log so the error will be spotted faster.